# Can I get tick count from GetLastWriteTime

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a file and I get it's last write time via `GetLastWriteTime` method. Is it possible to see the number of milliseconds elapsed between the system is started and file is written. Is there any relation between them?

Comment: what do you mean by "system started", the time the machine was powered on ?

Comment: in msdn page it says Environment.TickCount Property: Gets the number of milliseconds elapsed since the system started.

Comment: No guarantee that it was last written during the current session. What exactly are you needing.

Comment: GetLastWriteTime returns a DateTime. Take that and the DateTime on the current session and convert that into ticks.

Comment: @Venovani how can I convert it into ticks? that's what i need

Comment: Try looking up how to get the current date and time into a DateTime object. Then convert it in terms of seconds, and multiply it by 1000. That should give you the ticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would do something like this:

`var ts = file.GetLastWriteTime() - DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(-Environment.TickCount);`

That will return you a `TimeSpan` object representing time between system boot up and file write time.

Note: if the file's last write time was before the system started, then the `TimeSpan` will be negative.

And you can use `ts.TotalMilliseconds` to get just what you want: the value in milliseconds.  But the `TimeSpan` object will also give you a full breakdown of the time span, should you want it.